# Is there an easy way to combine a piecewise curve into one curve?

Tags: curves, parametric

The problem related to shape below. I need to find a parametric equation curve that is split into four different equations depending on the range. How can piecewise equations be combined into a single equation. Is there a way for that?

$$f(t)=
\begin{cases}
\langle r_1\cos(t),r_1\sin(t)\rangle & -s\leq t \leq s\\
\langle r_2\cos(t),r_2\sin(t)\rangle & -s\leq t \leq s\\
\langle d\cos(t+s)+m\cos(s),d\sin(t+s)+m\sin(s)\rangle & 0\leq t \leq \pi\\
\langle d\cos(t-s)+m\cos(-s),d\sin(t-s)+m\sin(-s)\rangle & \pi\leq t \leq 2\pi\\
\end{cases}$$
Where $s$ is length of arc, $r_1<r_2,\quad d=\frac{r_2-r_1}{2},\quad m=\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect that to be possible?

Comment: I don't know sir. I look for a way. So I asked. @Lorago

Comment: One can certainly re-parameterize the arcs, say with parameter $u$, so that the full curve is traced once as $u$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. (One can even adjust the parameterization of each arc so that the entire curve is traced with a uniform speed.) But the parameterization will always be inherently piecewise.

Comment: You can use the Heaviside step function to block or admit each section.

Comment: How? @CyeWaldman